# Using an ngClass Directive Inside Another Directive Throws Console Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use ngClass inside my directive, and it is working but I am seeing a console error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Here is a simplified version of my directive which reproduces the issue:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myNgClass: '='
        },
        template: '<div ng-class="myNgClass">Hello World</div>'
    }
});
```

And here is how I am using it:

```
<my-directive my-ng-class="{'green':true}"></my-directive>
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/wwh80cen/) is a link to a jsFiddle.

Comment: Did any of the answers address your question? If so, consider accepting. Otherwise, please ask for clarifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first of all, this error is specific to the version of Angular that you are using (v1.2.1) - it was fixed in v1.2.5 ([working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1uHB6d0Fn8Mou2bW4Tlh?p=preview) with v1.2.5).

Second, you really shouldn't be using a two-way binding (`"="`) since you don't seem to need to change the value from inside the directive. Using `"="` unnecessarily creates 2 watchers.

You could definitely do one-way string binding (`"@"`), like so:

```
scope: {
  myNgClass: '@'
},
template: '<div ng-class="{{myNgClass}}">Hello World</div>'
```

but this will have a more limited use. For example you won't be able to pass a object (`$scope.greenStyle = { green: true };`) to your directive:

```
<my-directive my-ng-class="greenStyle"></my-directive>
```

It is better to use a one-way binding to expressions - `"&"`. This keeps a single watch and binds to an object - not string. `scope.myNgClass` becomes a function that returns the value of the bound expression:

```
scope: {
  myNgClass: '&'
},
template: '<div ng-class="myNgClass()">Hello World</div>'
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/skxggBUMnPJQwbtkYPgF?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `@` instead of `=`.

```
myNgClass: '@'
```

When you use `=` angular adds a $watch for changes to 'myNgClass'. When a $watch is added, angular adds $$hashKey to the object and "attempts" to assign the modified object back to where it came from (so that the source and destination have the same object).

The problem is when the $digest compares the object it has `{'green':'true', $$hashKey: '123546246'}` vs the evaluated expression `{'green':'true'}` the comparison fails so the $watch listener is run (NOTE: That part is just my theory. I don't know 100% that it's adding a hashKey, but i DO know that it's treating the objects as different instances and that's triggering the watch listener).
Since my-ng-class will always send back a new instance of that object it will always be different and will always trigger the watch listener.

If you want to keep using `=` you can (but there's no need). You just have to define your initial object once elsewhere before passing it in. You can use ng-init to do that, like this:

```
<my-directive ng-init="clazz={'green':'true'}" my-ng-class="clazz"></my-directive>
```

Comment: That does fix the console error, but now it works differently.  Now it is passing the whole object `class="{'green': true }"` instead of just `class="green"`.

Comment: That's what it was doing before too. Take a look at the edited answer for an alternative where you can keep using `=` if you want to.